# Determiner Problem

Tags: determiners

I wrote a sentence.
"People play many dangerous sports. The sports can harm them a  lot."

In this sentence, "The sports" refers to "many dangerous sports" in my first sentence.
But, Grammarly is identifying it as a mistake.

Why? help me please

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we're not here to debug Grammarly

Comment: You might *think* "The sports" refers to "many dangerous sports", but that's not really true. Native Anglophones would say ***those / these** sports*, for the avoidance of doubt. Except native speakers would much more likely rephrase to *People play many dangerous sports, **which** can harm them a lot.*

Comment: I do not think It will be right because I am trying to identify whether my logic is incorrect or this AI technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having never used Grammarly, I have no idea how accurate it might be, nor what specifics it may be considering in your sentence.  However, your use of "a lot" is ambiguous and seems a little awkward or unnatural.  I would consider rephrasing that part.  Given the context, saying "a lot" might imply *frequency*, as opposed to *degree*.  Unless you want it to be open to interpretation to both of these meanings, you might consider changing the expression to something like "...harm them greatly" or "...considerably harm them" or even "...cause them considerable harm."

As for the "The sports..." portion, perhaps Grammarly would like "These sports..." better, as this is more clear.  Technically, as written it is grammatically correct; it is just a little unnatural sounding, i.e. not entirely "idiomatic."